# Webpack DLL plugin not running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I'm having lots of trouble getting the webpack DLL plugin to work for me. It's work in the sense that the dll is being extracted, and the other bundle sizes are reducing, however when run in the browser I get the following error:

```
module.js from dll-reference [name]:1 Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function
at Object.../node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js (module.js from dll-reference [name]:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap dff23196bbd9943d1e33:678)
at fn (bootstrap dff23196bbd9943d1e33:88)
at Object.../node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/punycode/punycode.js (punycode.js:533)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap dff23196bbd9943d1e33:678)
at fn (bootstrap dff23196bbd9943d1e33:88)
at Object.../node_modules/url/url.js (url.js:24)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap dff23196bbd9943d1e33:678)
at fn (bootstrap dff23196bbd9943d1e33:88)
at Object.<anonymous> (client:6)
```

My config seems to be correct according to the docs and people on SO / github who have had the same error message.

webpack.development.js:

```
let fs = require('fs')
let path = require('path')

let webpack = require('webpack')

const { extractLegacy, extractModules } = require('./extract-text')

let defaultConfig = require('./webpack')

module.exports = Object.assign({}, defaultConfig, {
  cache: true,
  devtool: '#source-map',
  entry: Object.assign(defaultConfig.entry, {
    'webpack-dev-server/hot/client?https://app.local.app:8080/':
    'webpack-dev-server/client?https://app.local.app:8080/',
    'dll.vendor': '../build/dll.vendor.js'
  }),
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    host: 'app.local',
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
     https: {
       key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../l ocalssl/server.key')),
       cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../localssl/server.crt'))
  },
stats: {
  cached: false,
  cachedAssets: false,
  children: false,
  chunks: false,
  chunkModules: false,
  chunkOrigins: false,
  depth: false,
  errors: true,
  errorDetails: true,
  hash: false,
  maxModules: 0,
  modules: false,
  providedExports: false,
  reasons: false,
  source: false,
  timings: false,
  usedExports: false
}
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
    }
  }),
extractLegacy,
extractModules,
new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
  manifest: require('../build/vendor.json'),
  name: '[name]',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
})
]})
```

webpack.dll.js

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
  vendor: [path.resolve(__dirname, './vendors.js')]
},
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    use: ['babel-loader?cacheDirectory']
  }
]
},
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
  filename: 'dll.[name].js',
  library: '[name]'
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.DllPlugin({
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../build', '[name].json'),
    name: '[name]'
  })
],
resolve: {
  modules: ['node_modules']
}
}
```

package.json

```
 {
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "src/index.js",
   "dependencies": {
     "@heroku/foreman": "^2.0.2",
     "adm-zip": "^0.4.7",
"amqplib": "^0.5.2",
"autoprefixer": "7.1.3",
"aws-sdk": "^2.104.0",
"babel-cli": "6.16.0",
"babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
"babel-loader": "6.2.5",
"babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes": "^5.1.2",
"babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.7.1",
"babel-plugin-recharts": "1.1.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.22.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.22.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.22.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "6.16.0",
"babel-preset-es2015-node": "^6.1.1",
"babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
"basic-auth": "1.1.0",
"bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
"body-parser": "1.17.2",
"bookshelf": "0.10.4",
"bookshelf-cascade-delete": "2.0.1",
"bookshelf-paranoia": "0.9.0",
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
"bunyan": "1.8.10",
"bunyan-middleware": "0.4.0",
"change-case": "3.0.1",
"cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
"classnames": "2.2.5",
"compression": "1.7.0",
"connect-flash": "0.1.1",
"connect-redis": "3.3.0",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"cookies-js": "^1.2.3",
"cron": "1.2.1",
"css-loader": "0.28.4",
"csvtojson": "^1.1.7",
"date-holidays": "^1.2.0",
"deep-equal": "^1.0.1",
"deep-freeze": "^0.0.1",
"deserialize-error": "^0.0.3",
"draft-convert": "^1.4.8",
"draft-extend": "^1.5.0",
"draft-js": "^0.10.1",
"elasticsearch": "^13.0.1",
"email-templates": "^2.7.1",
"eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.1.2",
"eslint-plugin-flow-vars": "^0.5.0",
"express": "4.16.0",
"express-request-id": "1.4.0",
"express-session": "1.15.3",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
"file-loader": "0.11.2",
"flow": "^0.2.3",
"forever": "^0.15.3",
"helmet": "3.8.0",
"http-errors": "1.6.1",
"ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
"immutable": "^3.8.1",
"isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
"jackrabbit": "git+https://github.com/leonlau/jackrabbit.git#da554347132757cd81c39037dd527ee258d088b5",
"jsdom": "^11.5.1",
"json-loader": "0.5.4",
"json2csv": "^3.7.3",
"knex": "0.13.0",
"knex-migrate": "^1.3.0",
"less": "2.7.1",
"less-loader": "2.2.3",
"lodash": "4.16.4",
"md5": "^2.2.1",
"microtime-nodejs": "^1.0.0",
"moment": "2.15.2",
"moment-range": "^2.2.0",
"mongo": "0.1.0",
"mongodb": "2.2.11",
"nconf": "0.8.4",
"newrelic": "^2.6.0",
"node-sass": "^4.5.3",
"normalizr": "^3.2.1",
"numeral": "^2.0.6",
"oauth": "git+https://github.com/Dakuan/node-oauth.git#24bc9bec128b5ca718eb5cd6e319cd22129a5158",
"oauth2-server": "^2.4.1",
"ordinal-numbers": "^1.0.3",
"pdfmake": "^0.1.32",
"pg": "6.1.6",
"pg-hstore": "2.3.2",
"pluralize": "^7.0.0",
"postcss": "6.0.10",
"postcss-loader": "1.1.1",
"prettyjson": "^1.2.1",
"proxyquire": "^1.7.11",
"pug": "2.0.0-beta6",
"quill": "^1.3.1",
"react": "^15.4.1",
"react-addons-perf": "^15.4.2",
"react-autosize-textarea": "^0.4.4",
"react-datepicker": "^0.40.0",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-joyride": "^1.10.1",
"react-redux": "4.4.5",
"react-router": "2.8.1",
"react-router-redux": "4.0.7",
"react-scroll": "^1.5.5",
"react-scrollbar": "^0.5.1",
"react-slick": "^0.15.0",
"react-slider": "^0.7.0",
"react-sparklines": "^1.6.0",
"react-stripe-elements": "^1.0.1",
"react-table": "^6.6.0",
"react-textarea-autosize": "^5.0.6",
"react-toggle": "^4.0.2",
"react-tooltip": "^3.2.10",
"recharts": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
"recompose": "^0.24.0",
"redfour": "^1.0.2",
"redis": "2.6.3",
"redux": "3.6.0",
"redux-devtools-extension": "^1.0.0",
"redux-form": "^7.1.1",
"redux-logger": "2.7.0",
"redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
"redux-saga-test-plan": "^3.3.1",
"redux-thunk": "2.1.0",
"request": "^2.78.0",
"request-promise": "^4.2.2",
"rewire": "^2.5.2",
"s3": "^4.4.0",
"sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
"sendgrid": "4.7.1",
"serialize-error": "^2.1.0",
"simulant": "^0.2.2",
"snyk": "^1.41.1",
"soap": "^0.21.0",
"socket.io": "^2.0.2",
"socket.io-client": "^2.0.2",
"socket.io-cookie-parser": "^1.0.0",
"socket.io-redis": "^5.1.0",
"stripe": "^5.1.0",
"style-loader": "^0.19.1",
"url-loader": "0.5.7",
"url-parse": "^1.1.9",
"urlencode": "^1.1.0",
"uuid": "2.0.3",
"validate.js": "^0.11.1",
"velocity-animate": "^1.4.0",
"velocity-react": "^1.2.1",
"victory": "0.13.7",
"webpack": "^3.10.0",
"xml2json": "^0.11.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"ava": "^0.24.0",
"babel-jest": "16.0.0",
"babel-register": "6.16.3",
"chromedriver": "^2.34.1",
"enzyme": "^2.7.0",
"eslint": "3.8.1",
"eslint-config-prettier": "2.9.0",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.30.0",
"eslint-plugin-lodash-fp": "2.1.3",
"eslint-plugin-react": "6.4.1",
"fetch-mock": "5.5.0",
"flow-bin": "^0.57.2",
"husky": "^0.14.3",
"lint-staged": "^6.0.0",
"nightwatch": "^0.9.19",
"nock": "9.0.2",
"node-mocks-http": "^1.5.4",
"nodemon": "1.11.0",
"npm-run-all": "^4.1.1",
"nyc": "8.3.2",
"prettier": "1.9.2",
"ps-node": "^0.1.4",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.1",
"react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.6",
"redux-mock-store": "^1.2.2",
"selenium-server-standalone-jar": "^3.8.1",
"sinon": "1.17.6",
"supertest": "2.0.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.0"
},
"ava": {
"require": [
  "babel-register",
  "babel-polyfill",
  "ignore-styles"
],
"babel": "inherit"
},
"nyc": {
"extension": [
  ".jsx",
  ".js"
],
"include": [
  "src"
],
"exclude": [
  "tests",
  "build",
  "node_modules"
]
},
"engines": {
"node": "8.9.x",
"npm": "5.5.x",
"yarn": "1.3.2"
},
}
```

folder structure:

```
  -- build
  -- src
  -- webpack
```

Comment: Seems odd that you're processing it with Babel

Comment: Perhaps! Either way, removing the babel bit does not make the error go away :(

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: no solution yet!